# Automating a powershell command that prompts for user input?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I execute the command

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

and sometimes it prompts

```
Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

How do I automate the answer to 'A' when it prompts for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enable-PSRemoting -Confirm:$false`